# Saving a list of dictionaries to file python 3

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, save

Hi  I have to  write a function that takes as arguments dictionaries and file name and saves it into a file with each dictionary in new line:
For example this is the list of dictionaries:

```
[[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'aa': 2, 'bb': 3}]
```

This is my code:

```
def write_list_of_ngram_dicts(list_of_dicts, filename):
    import json
    open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    for dic in list_of_dicts:
        json.dump(dic, filename)
        filename.write("\n")
```

But sadly it doesn't work and I don't understand why?, maybe there is another way to do it?
thank you:)

Comment: In which format you want to save the file?

Comment: in my home work there is no specific file format just saving

Comment: Ok @ZivAqua....

Comment: If it's without any formats you can simply just- ```filename.write("[[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'aa': 2, 'bb': 3}]]")```

Comment: and it will save it in new line each dictionary?

Comment: Oh so you want a dictionary in it's separate line, like- {'a': 1, 'b': 2}<br>
{'aa': 2, 'bb': 3}

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not good enough for a Stack Overflow question. What happened when you tried to run the code? How is that different from what you want to happen?

Comment: it   didnt passed  a test and returned :module:  ngrams  function:   write_list_of_ngram_dicts
parameters:   [[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'aa': 2, 'bb': 3}], 'check.txt']
other options:    {'output': ''}
AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'write'")
result_code write_list_of_ngram_dicts_wlsnd1 testingFailed 1
incorrect:   +0

Answer (score 4):

This will print each list in new line

```
def write_list_of_ngram_dicts(list_of_dicts, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for dic in list_of_dicts:
            data=json.dumps(dic) 
            file.write(data)
            file.write("\n")
```

This will print each dictionary in new line

```
def write_list_of_ngram_dicts(list_of_dicts, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for lists in list_of_dicts:
            for dic in lists:
                data=json.dumps(dic) 
                file.write(data)
                file.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your question?

**WILL CREATE A FILE WITH NAME: check.txt**

```py
d = [[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'aa': 2, 'bb': 3}], "check.txt"]

with open(d[1], "w") as f:
    for i in range(len(d[0])):
        f.write(str(d[0][i])+"\n")
```

RESULT:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'aa': 2, 'bb': 3}
```

Hope so that this information is useful to and answers you question!
Happy Coding!

Comment: but what if the list of dictionaries is longer then 2?if i want it to work for every possible number of dictionaries htats   why i thought of using for loop

Comment: @ZivAqua please check out the edited post, to resolve your problem of multiple dictionaries

Comment: It works fine for me. What doesnt work for you @ZivAqua

Comment: i have  test that run on my prgram and tell me if it is correct:module:  ngrams  function:   write_list_of_ngram_dicts
parameters:   [[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'aa': 2, 'bb': 3}], 'check.txt']
other options:    {'output': ''}
KeyError(0)
result_code write_list_of_ngram_dicts_wlsnd1 testingFailed 1
incorrect:   +0

Comment: What is ```check.txt'``` and ```other options``` it's not a dictionary you only told to write dicts on new lines, you only told me do it on multiple dicts such as: ```[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'aa': 2, 'bb': 3}, {'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 2}, {'aaaa': 1, 'bbbb': 2}]]```

Comment: i think it is part of the test that is running

Comment: You only told me to do it on dicts.

Comment: yes it is only for dics the funciton takes as an argument a list of dicjs and a file name that i want the file to ce called

Comment: Oh, Ok, will do

Comment: I have edited the post check it out @ZivAqua